# LibGDX Box2D Physics Direction Inverted

Tags: kotlin, libgdx, box2d

For some reason in my world physics direction is inverted.I mean -9.8 gravity is acting like 9.8 gravity so objects are going up.Horizontal velocity is also inverted.Something must be wrong with x,y coordinate system.

world = World(Vector2(0f,-9.8f),false)   pushes objects up

is there a problem with PPM ?

```
package com.mygdx.game

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.*
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Box2DDebugRenderer



class MyGdxGame : ApplicationAdapter() {

    val PPM = 32f

    private lateinit var camera : OrthographicCamera
    private lateinit var world :World
    private lateinit var player:Body
    private lateinit var platform:Body

    private lateinit var b2dr:Box2DDebugRenderer
    override fun create() {
        var w = Gdx.graphics.width
        var h = Gdx.graphics.height
        camera = OrthographicCamera()
        camera.setToOrtho(false, w / 2f, h / 2f)

        world = World(Vector2(0f,-9.8f),false)
        b2dr = Box2DDebugRenderer()

        player = createBox(2f,10f,32,32,false)
        platform = createBox(0f,0f,64,32,true)

    }



    override fun render() {
        update(Gdx.graphics.deltaTime)

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f)
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
        b2dr.render(world,camera.combined.scl(PPM))

    }

    override fun resize(width: Int, height: Int) {

        camera.setToOrtho(false, width / 2f, height / 2f)
    }


    override fun dispose() {
        world.dispose()
      b2dr.dispose()

    }

    fun update(delta:Float){
         world.step(1/60f,6,2)
        inputUpdate(delta)
         cameraUpdate(delta)



    }
    fun inputUpdate(delta:Float){
        var horizontalForce = 0f;
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT)){
          horizontalForce -=1

        }
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT)){
          horizontalForce +=1

        }
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.UP)){
            player.applyForceToCenter(0f,300f,false)
        }
        player.setLinearVelocity(horizontalForce*5,player.linearVelocity.y)
    }
    fun cameraUpdate(delta:Float){
     var position:Vector3 = camera.position
        position.x = player.position.x * PPM // if you get box2d units multiply with ppm
        position.y = player.position.y * PPM
        camera.position.set(position)
        camera.update()

    }
    fun createBox(x:Float,y:Float,width:Int,height:Int,isStatic:Boolean):Body{
     var pBody:Body
        var def:BodyDef
        def = BodyDef()
        if(isStatic){
            def.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody
        }
        else{
            def.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody
        }

        def.position.set(x/PPM,y/PPM)
        def.fixedRotation = true
        pBody = world.createBody(def)

        var shape:PolygonShape = PolygonShape()
        shape.setAsBox(width/2/PPM,height/2/PPM) // takes from center this is 32x32 box
        pBody.createFixture(shape,1.0f)

        shape.dispose()//clean it
        return pBody

    }

}
```

Comment: in what orientation (landscape, portrait) do you want to play the game?

Comment: if you want your object to go in the different direction, use 9.8f instead of -9.8f

Answer (score 0):

It's all correct with box2d and your code.

-9.81 pushes objects up and 9.81 pull objects down.

In the `World` constructor, you set the gravity of the world.

> And Gravity is a natural phenomenon by which all things with mass or
>   energy—including planets, stars, galaxies, and even light—are brought
>   toward (or gravitate toward) one another.

Basic Gravity is the force with which object attract each other.

So on Earth gravity is the force with which objects are attracted to the center of the earth.

On Earth, we have a gravity of ~ 9.81 means all Objects will pull to the center of the earth with a force of ~ 9.81 m/s².

Finally is it logical that if gravity is a force which pulls objects down that -gravity will push objects up.

On Earth, we have a gravity of ~ 9.81 not a gravity of ~ -9.81.
If it were, we would all end up outside in the universe.